# Add support for Entity Framework in Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have the following project structure in my Azure function:

- Application.Function
- Application.Domain
- Application.Infrastructure

This works fine. All the dependencies are resolved without any errors.

However, when I setup Entity Framework in my `Infrastructure` layer, and I'm trying to run the application, I get the following error:

> webjobsbuilderextensions.cs not found

When I remove all the Entity Framework related things and try to run the application, it works again.

In my `Startup.cs` I have the following code snippet:

```
builder.Services.AddDomain(connectionString);
```

Application.Domain.Injections:

```
public static class Injections
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddDomain(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ISalesItemService, SalesItemService>();
        services.AddPersistence(connectionString)

        return services;
    }
}
```

Application.Infrastructure.Injections:

```
public static class Injections
{
        public static IServiceCollection AddPersistence(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
        {
            services.AddTransient<ISalesItemDataService, SalesItemDataService>();

            services.AddDbContext<IOnePlmSubContext, OnePlmSubContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString),
                ServiceLifetime.Transient,
                ServiceLifetime.Transient);

            return services;
        }
}
```

Has anyone else experienced the same issue that I have? Can't I have this kind of layered structure when working with Azure functions?

Comment: What version of EF and .net core are you using ?

Comment: @auburg: Im using the version 5.0.6 of EF and .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Try downgrading version of EF Core to 3.1 and re-build and re-test the function.

Answer (score 0):

Summarize the comments for other communities reference:

Just downgrade version of EF Core to 3.1 and re-build the function, then re-rest the funciton, it works.